# Is it allowed to avoid classes?

Tags: python, oop

Programming with the object-oriented paradigm is some kind of best-practice method in developing large programs. That is the opinion of the Java-community, the C++ community and also from the Python community. In all these languages, it's possible to use the “class” statement for creating a subspace in which local variables and local methods are declared. But what, if this concept is wrong?

Plain C programmers never used classes, instead they are grouping their sourcecode in files. File1 is class1, file2 is class2 and so on. On top of each file a struct is used to manage the variables. According to c programmers this concept works great. But Forth programmers are also not convinced that object oriented programming is a good idea. In the new Forth200x standard no word for class is available, instead the Forth community groups the sourcecode also in files, better known as screens. It seems, that class-less object oriented programming is possible. Let us construct a simple example in Python.

[image: classlessgui]

```
### main.py ###
import physics, gui

def main():
  gui.widgetinput.bind("<Return>", parseinput)
  gui.tkwindow.mainloop() 
def parseinput(event):
  name=gui.widgetinput.get()
  if name=="move":
    physics.move(20,0)
  print physics.player

main()

### physics.py ###
player=(100,100)

def move(x,y):
  global player
  player=(player[0]+x,player[1]+y)

### gui.py ###
import Tkinter

tkwindow = Tkinter.Tk()
tkwindow.geometry("650x400")
# info
widgetinfo = Tkinter.Label(tkwindow, text="input")
widgetinfo.place(x=100, y=100)
# input
widgetinput = Tkinter.Entry(tkwindow)
widgetinput.place(x=140, y=100)
```

The surprising thing is, that this program will get started with the python interpreter without any error messages. If the user enters the command “move” into the textfield, a request is send to the physics module and the position is updated. In an object-oriented programming style each module would be equal to a class, but in the sourcecode no explicit classes are used.

What is the name for a class-less programming style? Is it from a software engineering side allowed to do so?

Comment: What's allowed depends on your project and company guidelines

Comment: *"Plain C programmers never used classes"* because C doesn't have classes. And there's a lot of other programming paradigms: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_paradigm

Comment: I'm not sure I see what's particularly surprising about the above program working...

Comment: @AKX The surprising thing is, that the subfunction of a module is called with “physics.move()”. That means, it's referencing to an external file. In object-oriented programming this principle is quite common, because it's possible to call a method from an object. But here, there is no object, instead the modules are distributed over files. That means, it's not completely anti-oop because some kind of hierarchy is there. I'm not sure, under which conditions this programming style will break everything. I would argue, that this looks wrong, but I don't know why.

Comment: Close voters:  the OP didn't know what paradigms were. No opinion here.

Comment: @ManuelRodriguez If you like, you can imagine Python modules to be akin to singleton classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called [procedural programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedural_programming), and there isn't any reason to shy away from it if that's what you want to use.  Many Python scripts can be seen as procedural since they are run top-to-bottom and often intersperse commands and operations in that sequence.

The other paradigm involving classes is called [object-oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming).

You can use **whichever one you wish** so long as you and the other contributors to your code agree on this paradigm.

Answer (score 2):

Python can be an [object oriented language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming), [functional language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming), or [procedural language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedural_programming). Only object-oriented languages use classes and objects. All of them work fine, so you can use whichever one you chose. However, there are some libraries that require using one of these paradigms, so you may need to use one that you don't usually use with some libraries.